# OAuth implicit flow security with PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, oauth, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, authorization

I'm implementing an authorization server for our Web API 2 RESTful API using Bearer tokens.  To give some context, I am building an MVC web application as well as a PhoneGap mobile application (to be deployed to both iOS and Android) that will consume the RESTful API.  I've done a lot of research on the subject, and understand I want to go with the *authorization code* flow for my MVC app (as the client secret will be kept safe), however, it is my understanding that I must use the *implicit grant* flow for the PhoneGap application, with it being a purely client side application it is assumed it cannot hold a secret.

With that said, I'm still fighting over my understanding of the security implications of the implicit grant flow.  When executed in a browser, I understand it to be *somewhat* secure (by validating the redirect uri, short-lived tokens, etc).  However, because PhoneGap will execute within its own browser instance (thus returning the token via hash fragment that I will need to parse), how does this lock down the API to only my PhoneGap client?

What's to stop a malicious hacker from simply stealing the client_id (embedded in the HTML/JS) and build their own PhoneGap application (or any other) and simply go through the implicit authorization/authentication process, thus spoofing the "approved" or "official" PhoneGap app?  This problem does not seem specific to my API - does this mean this problem exists for all API's out there that implement the implicit flow (including the big players e.g. Facebook, Twitter, etc.)?  How can I prevent this from happening, does it mean I have to deny/not implement the implicit flow?  If so, how do I consume the API *securely* from my PhoneGap application?

Thanks!

Comment: What I was thinking to do because I've already implemented this in a website, is to create a special page for just the phones to signup/login and then redirect them back with a session token they can use. Further authentication requests are sent via SSL with the token as part of the HEAD or BODY is what I'm thinking to do. I'll update this as an answer if I actually implement it (keepin' it real).

Answer (score 2):

Oauth2 Implicit flow in general is not secure. Like you mentioned, anyone can see your `client_id` and can create a login URL to spoof users, and can steal `access_token`. This is possible with any service that uses Oauth2 implicit flow including big players.

Spam apps are actually doing this with Instagram, they use someone else's `client_id` to allow login,collect `access_token` and are using it to spam like/comment on Instagram.

Oauth2 authorization code grant flow is [**possible**](https://github.com/krisrak/jquery-cordova-oauth2) to implement in Phonegap app, but is not recommended since you have to store `client_secret` in HTML/JS. Same with Implicit grant flow, it is possible in Phonegap, but people can get your `client_id` and spoof users.

One way you can make it a bit more secure in Phonegap app is by using Oauth2 authorization code grant flow, after you get the `code` from redirect, `POST` it to your server with an hash to validate, and your server can do the actual Oauth2 `POST` to the service API with `client_secret` to get `access_token`. So in this case `client_secret` is not in the app HTML/JS, but is on your server. (This can also be spoofed by hacker, but you have a bit more control)

Comment: Hmm this is a good idea.  As you said, it can still be spoofed by a hacker (using the same method as spoofing the implicit grant), however how would I have more control / restrict access to only my phone gap application?  Would there be a way to detect where the request is coming from [from the MVC app] and deny if it isn't my mobile app?  Couldn't this be spoofed too?